# List comprehensions and one line for-loops

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, memory, generator

If you do this list comprehension:

```
squares = [x**2 for x in range(100000)]
```

It would take up a lot of memory, so you could do the same thing using a generator:

```
squares = (x**2 for x in range(100000))
```

Now let's say I want to use a single line for-loop to print all of those squares:

```
[print(square) for square in squares]
```

**My question is**: Is printing this way creating a list (it looks like a list comprehension)? If so, does that list get stored in the memory? (If it does, it would make no sense to use a generator when creating the `squares`, because those would get stored in the other list anyway.) And another thing: If you do this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

without assigning it to any variable, do those values get stored in the memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without assigning it to a name the list *won't* get stored in memory since there's no reference holding it (initially. memory *will* be allocated for it but it is immediately freed since (C)Python can see you aren't using it*).

Beyond that, printing with:

```
[print(square) for square in squares]
```

is highly inefficient; you're using a list-comprehension just for the *side effect* of printing, a list that holds the *result* of the `print` function call (its return value) is populated.

This means you'll end up with a list of `None`'s which is created *just to be dumped*, not much use in it.

You are better off using a generator with a `for` loop as @user312016 suggests in his answer. The generator will yield on demand and no extra list will be created.

<sub>*In interactive mode, things are different since you have the name `_` being used as the name of the most recent expression computed. There, the list gets stored in memory until the next expression overrides the value attached to `_`.</sub>

Comment: An important note, they will still be created in memory by the interpreter and then destroyed by the garbage collector because the lack of references.

Comment: Yes yes @user312016 , that's why I wrote *"initially memory will be allocated but it is immediately freed since Python can see you aren't using it"* :-). I interpreted OPs "stored in memory" question as asking if the memory actually persists *after* the statement has executed. (in interactive mode `_` keeps it around, but that's an exception)

Comment: Woops, I missed this part

Comment: I usually edit my answers heavily after posting, adding things as they pop in my head.

Comment: Ok, I understand, so the list that hasn't been assigned to anything gets deleted from memory immediately after the interpreter gets out of that list. Is this correct?

Comment: @Alex pretty much, yes. (C)Python memory is managed by references to objects (and, assigning it to a name increases the reference count for it). If an object doesn't have any references to it, it gets garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is creating a `list` and it is stored in memory, you shouldn't be using list comprehensions as single lines for loops, that's not what they are for.

You could do:

```
for square in (x**2 for x in range(100000)):
    print(square)
```